# Array can't be assigned

Tags: c

I am new to programming and am currently    struggling with assigning a  value into an array. I would like to store the input word length into an array. But it seems that when I reassign the value in the array (from 0 to the length of the words) the array refused store them and when I print the array the array is empty (doesn't   even have any zeroes).

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define OUT 0
#define IN 1

int main()
{
    int n_words[10];
    int c, nw, nc, state;
    state = OUT;
    nw = nc = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i){
        n_words[i] = 0;
    }

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
      ++nc;
      if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'){
        --nc;  // So that it doesn't count the spaces
        n_words[nw - 1] = nc;
        printf("Words number: %d has %d characters\n", nw - 1, nc);
        nc = 0;
        state = OUT;
      }
      else if(state == OUT){
        state = IN;
        ++nw;
      }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
      printf("%d, ", n_words[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
n_words[nw - 1] = nc;
```

When it is invoked for the first time, `nw` is 0.  Hence you are assigning a value to `n_works[-1]`, which is undefined behavior.

I'm not sure why you are writing to the end of the array with `[nw-1]`.  And you don't need `nc` to track the letter count of the current word.  You can continually increment `n_words[nw]`.  I think this is closer to what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define OUT 0
#define IN 1

int main()
{
    int n_words[10] = { 0 };  // zero-init the entire array
    int nw, state;

    state = OUT;
    nw = 0;

    while (nw < 10) {

        int c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }

        int isWhitespace = ((c == ' ') || (c == '\n') || (c == '\t'));

        if (isWhitespace && state == OUT) {
            continue;
        }

        state = IN;

        if (isWhitespace) {
            state = OUT;
            printf("Word number: %d has %d characters\n", nw, n_words[nw]);
            nw++;
        }
        else {
            n_words[nw]++;  // same as n_words[nw] = n_words[nw] + 1;
        }
    }

    // after breaking out of the loop - need to finish the last word
    if (state == IN) {
        state = OUT;
        nw++; // complete the last word
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nw; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", n_words[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re “When it is invoked for the first time, `nw` is 0”: Only if the input starts with white space.